# Show that $H \cap gK$ is either empty or is equal to the coset of $K \cap H$ in $H$ for subgroups $H,K <G$ and $g \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Problem Statement**

> Suppose $H,K < G$ are subgroups of a group $G$. Prove that for all $g \in G$, $H \cap gK$ is either empty or is equal to a coset of $K \cap H$ in $H$.

---

A quick question to get out of the way: The phrase term "Coset of $K \cap H$ in $H$" what exactly does this term suggest, in symbols? Because in reference to cosets I've only been exposed to the term "left coset (of $H$) by $g$" which is, of course $gH$. So, does this term mean that $h(K \cap H)$? Or potentially does it mean, $K \cap gH$? I'm a bit confused on the terminology here so some clarification would go a long way to helping decipher how to approach this problem.

---

Conceptually then, I believe this is what I know and what I want to show to prove the above:

$H \cap gK = \emptyset$ when $H$ and $gK$ share no elements in common. So, suppose that $H \cap gK$ is nonempty. That is, $f$ is any element such that $f \in H \cap gK$. This means that $f \in H$ and $f \in gK$.

Now, we want to show that the inclusion of an arbitrary element $f$ in the intersection of a subgroup $H$ and a coset of another subgroup $gK$ with an element of the group implies that that arbitrary element is also an element of a coset of $K \cap H$ in $H$ (whatever that means exactly.) And, conversely, that an element of a coset of $K \cap H$ in $H$ implies that it is an element of $H \cap gK$. So that we show containment in both directions. Correct?

Comment: It means: $h(H\cap H)$

Comment: $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$. So as any subgroup it has cosets, which are subsets of $H$ of the form $h(H\cap K)$ where $h\in H$. This is exactly the definition you know, just instead of "$G$ and $H$" we use "$H$ and $H\cap K$".

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the clarification, that makes sense. Now, if you don't mind me asking, for the first containment can I say that since $f \in H \cap gK$ that means that $f \in H$ and $f \in gK$ and that implies $f \in h(H \cap K)$ since $h(H \cap K)$ is the set of products of an element $h \in H$ with all elements that are in both $H$ and $K$... 

...actually, I'm not quite seeing where I should be making the connection here: Obviously since $f \in H$ then if it were just $hH$ that'd make sense... but it'd also be trivial since $hH = H$. I'm having trouble intuiting the coset elements

Comment: @NumericalDisintegration It is not clear what is $h$ in your comment though. You can start by assuming the intersection is not empty, so there is some element $h\in H\cap gK$. (for a fixed $g$) Now show that $H\cap gK$ equals the coset $h(H\cap K)$ for this specific $h$. Now try to show a two sided inclusion between sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coset of $K\cap H$ in $H$ means $h(K\cap H)$ for some $h\in H$. Therefore we want to show that if $H\cap gK\neq \varnothing$ for $g\in G$, then $H\cap gK=h(K\cap H)$ for some $h\in H$.

Let $g\in G$ and suppose that $H\cap gK\neq \varnothing$. There exists $x=h=gk$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. The natural guess is that $H\cap gK=x(K\cap H)$.

First note that $g=xk^{-1}$. Hence $gK=xk^{-1}K=xK$. Also $xH=H$ as $x\in H$. Therefore
$$x(K\cap H)=x(H\cap K)=xH\cap xK=H\cap gK$$
as claimed.